# find candidate key from fd

Tags: database, functional-dependencies, candidate-key

Hi I need a little help with finding **candidate key** with FD:

given relation : R{x,y,z,s,t,u,w}

FD: {s->x , t->y , x->y ,xy->tuz}

is the candidate key {s,w} ?

Comment: Yes, it is the only candidate key.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when a process allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your reference. [ask] [help] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Basic questions are SO faqs, research before considering asking & reflect research.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.